# How can I compare and specific line of a text file?

Tags: file, batch-file, compare

Example

```
    (
Line1: echo echo example
Line2: echo echo example
Line3: echo echo example
Line4: echo echo File Example
) > File1.txt

(
Line1: echo echo example
Line2: echo echo example
Line3: echo echo File
Line4: echo echo File
) > File2.txt
```

Want to compare just the Line4 if its equal or not but 
discarding the other lines. Return false in this case

Comment: Which kind of batch file? Bash script? Powershell script? Python script? PHP script?

Comment: @JuanLago: Well, you could _read_ the description that appears when the mouse cursor is placed over the `batch-file` tag: _"A text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on MS-DOS, IBM OS/2 or Microsoft Windows"_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36252686.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q36252686_2.txt"

:: This part simply establishes the data IN the files

FOR %%a IN ("%filename1%" "%filename2%") DO DEL %%a 2>nul
FOR %%a IN (
"Line1: echo echo example"
"Line2: echo echo example"
"Line3: echo echo example"
"Line4: echo echo File Example"
) DO >> "%filename1%" ECHO(%%~a

FOR %%a IN (
"Line1: echo echo example"
"Line2: echo echo example"
"Line3: echo echo File"
"Line4: echo echo File"
) DO >> "%filename2%" ECHO(%%~a

:: line to match

SET /a matchonline=4
:: lines to skip
SET  /a skiplines=matchonline-1
SET "skiplines=skip=%skiplines%"

IF %matchonline%==1 SET "skiplines=" 

FOR /f "usebackq%skiplines%delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "usebackq%skiplines%delims=" %%b IN ("%filename2%") DO (
  IF "%%a"=="%%b" (SET "result=true") ELSE (SET "result=false")
  GOTO done
 )
)
:done
ECHO match ON line %matchonline%=%result%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `filename1` and `filename2` to suit your circumstances. I generated your data into convenient filenames on my system for testing.

Read the first file, skipping the lines before the one to match and assign its contents to `%%a`. When that happens, repeat for the second file, to `%%b`

Set the result and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array to compare this kind of files like this :

```
@echo off
(
    echo Line1:example
    echo Line2:example
    echo Line3:example
    echo Line4:File
)> File1.txt

(
    echo Line1:example
    echo Line2:example
    echo Line3:File
    echo Line4:example
)> File2.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('Type "File1.txt"') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set File1_Line[!i!]=%%a
)
set File1_Line[4]
pause
::********************************************************
set i=0
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('Type "File2.txt"') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set File2_Line[!i!]=%%a
)
set File2_Line[4]
pause
::********************************************************
echo File1_Line[4]" = !File1_Line[4]!"
pause
echo File2_Line[4] = "!File2_Line[4]!"
pause
::********************************************************
IF /I "!File1_Line[4]!" equ "!File2_Line[4]!" ( echo TRUE 
 ) else (
echo False
)
pause
```